# Position the text/element on the right of the HTML document

Tags: html, css, position

What I want: **Stick text or an element to the right of the document, instead of window**.

However, without currently implementation (`position: absolute; right:0;`), when I resize the window, the text always stay on the right side of the window, even there is a scrollbar showing up (because the element on the top of that has a fixed width). When I scroll right, the text is not right aligned any more.

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/N5jc9/

Note that, I have no control on container1. Anyone having a good solution for this using CSS?

Comment: You might be looking for a `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put container 2 inside container 1 and make container 1's position relative.

Comment: Thanks! But I have no control on the `container1`.

Comment: Try wrapping container2 with another div that has position relative/fixed/absolute

Comment: Could you possibly give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:after` pseudo element and position it to the right of your `<body>` element. This of course will be evident only if you have set a fixed/min width for your `<body>` element.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/PPtD5/2/

**Code**:

```
body {
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
body::after {
    content: "This one sticks to the right of <body>";
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -120px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no control over `body` either.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand completely what control you have for container1, but if you apply display:inline-block to each class the text will appear to the right of the container 1

Comment: Basically the reason why container1 is there is to define the minimum width of the document. Unfortunately I cannot move the text in container1.